# Violation of foreign keys (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm amazed to see that the child table has some keys which parent table doesn't have and SQL Server didn't give any error when the data was inserted. I used `bcp` command to load data from `.csv` files into parent and child tables.

I can see the foreign keys constraints are enabled.

The constraints used in the child tables are :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].child WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_child_Parent] 
    FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] (company_id)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].child CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_child_Parent]
GO
```

When I'm inserting some records, then SQL Server throws errors for violation of foreign keys which is fine, but I'm confused why did SQL Server not raise any errors when this data was populated?

Also I re-verified the violation of foreign keys with existing records by executing below query and I got the expected error.

```
ALTER TABLE child
      WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
 GO
```

Comment: Data was added before the constraint was created I guess.

Comment: No no, The database was properly setup with these constraints before the data was inserted.

Comment: In that case, the bcp operation was ignoring the constraints, it's an option when to turn that on/off. The default in bcp is to ignore them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, bcp will ignore constraints when inserting data. If you want bcp to respect the constraints you need to enable that feature. [From the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.105).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> *CHECK_CONSTRAINTS*: 
>   Specifies that all constraints on the target table or view must be checked during the bulk-import operation. **Without the CHECK_CONSTRAINTS hint, any CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints are ignored**, and after the operation the constraint on the table is marked as not-trusted.

So the command you run should look like this:

```
bcp <current parameters> -h"CHECK_CONSTRAINTS"
```

Comment: Thanks David. BCP did show primary key violation though, why is it so ?

Comment: Because a primary key is a different type of constraint.

Comment: @SMor: So what ?. Well leave it, just read in the Docs and it is specifically mentioned that `UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, and NOT NULL constraints are always enforced.`